# Too few arguments Laravel Nova relatable query

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have a relationship that needs to be filtered differently depending on the Laravel Nova field it is being used to populate.

- A single **Process_type** has one or more **Process_justification**s attached as options (BelongsToMany)
- A single **Process_type** also has a single **Process_justification** set as a default (BelongsTo)

I'm using a relatable query to filter the available options for each of these two fields.

The two fields in my Process_type resource are as follows:

```
BelongsTo::make('Default', 'process_justification', Process_justification::class)
BelongsToMany::make('Options', 'process_justifications', Process_justification::class)
```

The relatable query looks like this:

```
public static function relatableProcess_justifications(NovaRequest $request, $query, Field $field)
        {
           
            if ($field instanceof BelongsTo) {
                //query builder to filter options
                ...........
            } else {
                //return all options
                return $query;
            }
        }
```

This pattern came from Laravel Nova documentation on Dynamic Relatable Models (https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/authorization.html#dynamic-relatable-methods)
It describes adding the field as a third parameter to the relatable query, then using it in a conditional to choose filter logic.

The error I'm getting is

*Too few arguments to function App\Nova\Process_type::relatableProcess_justifications(), 2 passed and exactly 3 expected*

My `make()` calls have three parameters as per the documentation, any idea what I'm missing?

I'm on Laravel 7.x and Nova 3.x

Comment: Which version of Nova 3?

Comment: Try reporting in Github [Laravel Nova Issues](https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues)